# Using Python and Selenium WebDriver to wait and click on a visible button

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I am having a torrid time trying to click on a button using Webdriver. The button is not visible until a value is entered in a prior field. I have tried adding sleeps and explicit waits but still no luck.

I am thinking it might have something to do with page javascript, but my skills don't quite extend that far. I am still learning so apoligies for my ugly code...

```
count=1
while count < 3:
time.sleep(2)
# Not the best way to select the button - but it works for now!
elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()
#Clear default amount
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("amount")
elem.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
elem.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
elem.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
elem.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
elem.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
elem.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
elem.send_keys("0.04")
print 'Entered Amount'
time.sleep(1)
elem.send_keys(Keys.TAB)

time.sleep(3)
elem.send_keys(Keys.TAB)

time.sleep(3)
elem.send_keys("\n")

# This finds the button - but it isn't visible
# elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()
time.sleep(6)
print 'Number of Payments = ', count
count = count + 1
print 'Finished!'
```

The website code looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn alpha centred-form-button ng-binding" ng-click="accountsPayCtrl.submit()" ng-disabled="!accountsPayCtrl.paymentSubmitted &amp;&amp;
          (!paymentForm.$valid || !accountsPayCtrl.inAmount || !accountsPayCtrl.payToken)" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">
        Pay $0.04 now
      </button>
```

There are no doubt more elegant ways to get to the end result too!

Error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\MW_Test\energyaust_Explicit_Wait.py", line 43, in <module>
elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 75, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 454, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be inter
acted with
Stacktrace:
at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///c:/users/ozmatt/appdata/local/temp/tmpupncqr/extensions/fxdriver@googleco
de.com/components/command-processor.js:9981)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///c:/users/ozmatt/appdata/local/temp/tmpupncqr/extensions/fxd
river@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12517)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/ozmatt/appdata/local/temp/tmpupncqr/extensions/fxdr
iver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12534)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///c:/users/ozmatt/appdata/local/temp/tmpupncqr/extensions/fxdriv
er@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12539)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///c:/users/ozmatt/appdata/local/temp/tmpupncqr/extensions/fxdriver@goog
lecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12481)
```

Comment: More elegant then `sleep` is explicit wait. Can you show how you tried using it?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `sleep` under (almost) any circumstance.
Instead, the Selenium API provides you with waits, Implicit and Explicit.
From the Selenium documentation:

> Implicit Waits An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM
>   for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or
>   elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is
>   0. Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance.

And for Explicit waits:

> Explicit Waits An explicit waits is code you define to wait for a
>   certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code. The
>   worst case of this is Thread.sleep(), which sets the condition to an
>   exact time period to wait. There are some convenience methods provided
>   that help you write code that will wait only as long as required.
>   WebDriverWait in combination with ExpectedCondition is one way this
>   can be accomplished.

Now, in your case, what you need is to have the element visible, or since you need to click on it, have it clickable:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "myDynamicElement")))
```

[Refer to this](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html) for usages of Explicit waits.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions guys. I had a colleague help me solve my issue and thought I would add it on here to perhaps help the next newbie like me.

Turns out that by not finding the detail to find the button, I was actually finding another, hidden button. I feel pretty silly but it is a good lesson!